# Laptop powers off within seconds of powering on; suspect battery issue; how to confirm?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, reboot

I sometimes leave my laptop open and on overnight -- laziness, I suppose. A few days ago, when i woke up, I saw my laptop was shut down. Odd as I didn't recall turning it off. When I tried to restart it, it would power off within seconds, before reaching any bios or splash login screen.

I did some research and found this was probably a hardware issue -- battery, power supply unit, motherboard, and cpu being the most likely culprits. The easiest thing for me to change was the battery, so I removed it and rebooted with the power adapter connected. Now I was able to restart the computer.

However, I then re-inserted the battery, to see if I could power on, maybe with the magic of 're-adjust things and try again.' It worked, and I used my laptop for the remainder of the day. However, the same thing happened that night -- the laptop was powered off when I woke up.

I've now used the laptop for several days sans battery, and had no issues. There have been no random shutdowns. So, it seems like I have a bad battery, but I want to know how I can determine this for sure before taking on the expense and inconvenience of searching for and buying a new battery. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: You have already confirmed it.  You removed the battery it worked, you insert the battery into the device, and the problem returned.  Just because temporary worked does not eliminate the battery from being the problem.  Of course a new battery is the simplest way to confirm the old battery is dead.

Answer (score 0):

You've already done most of the diagnostics; the machine works fine without the battery, but occasionally shuts down when the battery is present. To be sure, the most obvious next step would be to replace the battery and verify that the problem went away, but this is a step you would like to avoid.

It's hard to say for sure the problem is indeed with the battery. It's possible, though less likely, for batteries are far more prone to 'going bad', that there is a defect in the laptop's power circuitry. If so, the presence of a battery pack may trigger the problem, even though the battery itself is fine and replacing it will not help. The problem could even be as obscure as a bug in the motherboard's firmware or in software that periodically discharges the battery to extend its life.

However, you don't want to dive into these possible causes hunting for a problem you'll never find because you skipped the most likely culprit. Throroughly testing the battery pack is not practical if yours has more than three terminals, but there are some rudimentary checks you could do, like:

- measuring its output voltage and comparing it to the value printed on the back;
- discharging the battery, but not all the way, and measuring the voltage again;
- using the laptop without the external power supply and, if it doesn't shut down unexpectedly, seeing how long it takes to drain the batteries.

Unfortunately, even if the numbers seem reasonable, that's no guarantee the battery is perfectly fine. Replacing it to see whether that fixes the problem would be my next step either way.